# Creating new UI controls programmatically in visual c++

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli, windows-forms-designer

I have just started using visual studio c++ (2010) with windows forms, but have cannot for the life of me find out how to create new UI items in response to events. What I would want to happen is click a button, and have a new row, with a couple of text boxes and buttons appear, with onebutton to delete the row if I keep clicking, more rows will appear, named row0, row1 etcv. I looked at this page, (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984255(v=vs.71).aspx), about adding controls programmatically, but when I add a new text box inside a click event, the text box is only created inside the scope of the event (as expected!), but I want to be able to create it insde the newRow click event, but access it and . I thought of making a 'row' class, with row.text and row.deleteButton properties, and at each creation of a row, respective events will be created for button clicks and text edits.

Is there anyway to do this, ie a function that can be created that creates new objects by passing the required name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick for this to work is that you need to have declarations outside of the event handler to keep track of the newly added UI components. In the link you've given the added TextBox is locally scoped within the event function, and this will be removed from the heap (i.e. memory) when the event is finished.

So one solution would be to add a list of UI components to your form, and then have the events add to or remove from this list of components. To get this solution working you possibly need to read up on lists of objects (or possibly dictionaries) and how to handle these.

Sorry for a rather general answer, but the question is also very broad... :)